# Hide everything ( ui ) and display a google reward video

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in my game that is when a user presses on watch video it shows it successfully but it appears in the back not in the screen. How can I fix this?

The problem is :

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor ()
ButtonBehaviour:.ctor ()
GoogleMobileAds.Unity.RewardingAdBaseClient:CreateButtonBehavior ()
GoogleMobileAds.Unity.RewardingAdBaseClient:Show ()
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardedAd:Show ()
GameState:ShowRewardedVideo () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager/GameState.cs:492)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update ()
```

code line 492 :

```
public void ShowRewardedVideo () {
    if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded ()) {
        rewardedAd.Show (); # this is the 492 line
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot for the problem]

As you can see the ad appears at the back and not in screen.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#` ...

Comment: sorry for that done !

Comment: Did you create a GameObject with "new" somewhere in your code ?

Comment: Hmm, that is not the problem with the script, that is problem with your UI layer :+0

Comment: yes sorry for that i forget my GameObject i fix it in my code

Comment: now i try to build app but it say error with java after i updata iap unity why